# Minimize/Maximize/Show Browser Window and Tabs in C#

Tags: c#

I'm developing an application that launches various applications - executables, office documents and web applications. I need the buttons that launch the applications to behave exactly like the windows taskbar icons i.e. open an application, attach to the process and simply manage the window when the button for an open application is clicked. The Win32 ShowWindow command works well for the executables and office documents applications but for some reason does not work for Microsoft Edge. How do I manage the state of the window for the Edge browser and activate a specific tab within the browser?

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's because Edge isn't a Win32 application. It's a UWP application, so I'd actually be quite curious to know if Win32 commands would even work on it.

Comment: You're right, it is a UWP app. Are there ways to manage the windows of UWP apps similar to those provided by the Win32 commands?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935077/getting-hwnd-off-of-corewindow-object-in-uwp) seems to provide a way to get the handle of a UWP window, but it also says that there is nothing in the UWP API that takes a window handle as a parameter. Microsoft seemed to really crack down on that sort of stuff for UWP, so you might be out of luck.