# What is the UWP way of doing ImmAssociateContextEx()?

Tags: c++, uwp

In Win32, there is a [ImmAssociateContextEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imm/nf-imm-immassociatecontextex) function that accepts a HWND as the first parameter.

Somebody just told me that [you can't use a HWND in a UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39477014/111307).

So what's the way we can properly call ImmAssociateContextEx() (or equivalent) from a UWP app?

Comment: Looks like UWP has it's own Internationalization framework  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/globalizing-portal  If UWP is not listed in the __Requirements__ section (of your 1st link) then the API function is not available for that platform.

Comment: @RichardCritten Requirements says "Windows" under Target Platform -- certainly UWP is Windows..?

Comment: _"...Windows XP __[desktop apps only]__,..."_  It will not say this if available for use in a UWP app.

Comment: Then is there a UWP function that offers equivalent functionality?

Comment: As the link mentioned, UWP does not support APIs that accept HWND. Therefore, you can’t use ImmAssociateContextEx method in uwp app. Besides, I have to say that there is also no any equivalent api could handle the HWND in uwp app. Could you please tell me what your expected behavior is? What function do you want to achieve?